# Radio button not showing as checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, knockout.js, radio-button, html-helper

I'm using Knockout with MVC 4. My cshtml is:

```
...
<span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isActive, true, new { @class = "statusRadioButton", data_bind = "checked: isActive" })</span>
<span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isActive, false, new { @class = "statusRadioButton", data_bind = "checked: isActive" })</span>
...
```

My ko:

```
...
self.isActive = ko.observable(product.isActive);
...
```

It **updates the database correctly**, but it **doesn't show any radio button as checked when the page is loaded**. I tried also using the checked = "checked" html attribute and it doesn't work either. Any advice?

Comment: is `product.isActive` observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your product.isActive observable?  if so then you will need to execute the observable like `product.isActive()`

By initialising like `self.isActive = ko.observable(product.isActive());` you are only going to set it once.

Try turning it to observable like:

```
self.isActive = ko.computed(function() {
                                return product.isActive();
                             });
```

EDIT:
Try changing your radio buttons to this:

```
<span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isActive, true, new { @class = "statusRadioButton", data_bind = "checked: isActive", value="true" })</span>
<span>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.isActive, false, new { @class = "statusRadioButton", data_bind = "checked: isActive", value="false" })</span>
```

And writing your observable to use the boolean value in isActive as a string.

```
self.isActive = ko.computed(function() {
                                return product.isActive.toString();
                             });
```

Comment: I tried that and it throws and error, I think it's because isActive is a boolean, not a function. So I changed your code to return product.isActive; , now it doesn't break but the problem is still there.

Comment: from KO docs: 'For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute.'  They work differently to checkboxes. see my edit

Comment: Still nothing. I tried everything. Still updates the DB but doesn't show the checked radiobutton when the page loads.

Comment: Solved. I changed: self.isActive = ko.observable("True");